# Passing function prop to child component (via Link and Route components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using pure React with a Rails API backend.

I am fetching data from API and storing state in my Trips component. I have a Link component where I am able to pass the state to my NewTrip component, however `<Link>` does not allow me to pass functions.

I am able to pass functions to NewPage via render method on the Route component located at './routes/Index'.

But how do I pass the function from my Trips component? It's so much easier when passing as props to the component, the Router seems to be in the way!

'routes/Index.js'

```
export default (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/trips" exact component={Trips} />
      <Route path="/trip" render={(routeProps)=><NewTrip {...routeProps} />}/>
      <Route path="/trip/:id" exact component={Trip} />
      <Route path="/trip/:id/cost" exact component={NewCost} />
      <Route path="/trip/:id/edit" exact component={EditTrip} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

'components/Trips'

```
class Trips extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      trips: []
    }

    this.addTrip = this.addTrip.bind(this);
  }

  addTrip(trip) {
    const {trips} = this.state;
    trips.push(trip);
    this.setState({ trips: trips});
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: "/trip",
          state: {trips: trips, onAddTrip={this.addTrip}} // not allowed,
// but I want to pass this function to the 
// Component which is rendered by the Route in Index.js
        }}
        className="btn custom-button">
          Create New Trip
      </Link>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide/mark in the code the thing you want to do and you cannot?  What does `does not allow me to pass functions` exactly mean, and where it applies ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) of the `Trips` component and have it in your 'routes/Index.js'. (it will need to be a component now, not just an export).

'routes/Index.js'

```
export default class Routes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      trips: []
    }

    this.addTrip = this.addTrip.bind(this);
  }

  addTrip(trip) {
    const {trips} = this.state;
    trips.push(trip);
    this.setState({ trips: trips});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/trips" exact component={Trips} />
          <Route path="/trip" render={(routeProps)=>
            <NewTrip addTrip={this.addTrip} trips={this.state.trips} {...routeProps} />
          }/>
          <Route path="/trip/:id" exact render={(routeProps)=>
            <Trip addTrip={this.addTrip} trips={this.state.trips} {...routeProps} />
          }/>
          <Route path="/trip/:id/cost" exact component={NewCost} />
          <Route path="/trip/:id/edit" exact component={EditTrip} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

'components/Trips'

```
class Trips extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const trips = this.props.trips
    return (
      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: "/trip",
        }}
        className="btn custom-button">
          Create New Trip
      </Link>
    )
  }
}
```

It might be better to have the state even higher up in the `App` component, but you didn't provide that, so this has to do :)

Comment: Thanks, this seems the best idea, this is as high as it can go, my App component looks like this : 
```import React from "react";
import Routes from "../routes/Index";

export default props => <>{Routes}</>;
```

Comment: Yup, lifting the state farther up is completely unnecessary here. Wouldn't mind if you accepted this answer if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass functions using `state` in react router Link.

```
    <Link
        to={{
          pathname: "/trip",
          state: {trips: trips, onAddTrip: this.addTrip}
        }}
        className="btn custom-button">
          Create New Trip
    </Link>
```

And then in `/trip`, you retrieve and use the function like this:

```
this.props.location.state.addTrip();
```

Comment: won't there be an issue with the `<Trip/>` unmounting and its state being inaccessible?

Comment: @AdamJeliński I generally think this kinds of code usually signals bad design. it's not legitimate to pass functions with native capabilities and on the other hand, simple serializable functions also can be easily imported / exported.

Comment: @Mahdi I have tried this already and it throws the following error:
```Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': function () { [native code] } could not be cloned.```